# How to remove UsernameToken element from SOAP header of service response

Tags: c#, soap, asmx

I need to develop an asmx service to support an existing java client. The client uses oasis security headers in request and response. After referring a lot of blogs, i was able to have the service accept the SOAP headers with oasis security.
One unresolved issue remains around response. The root element for response header is same but it doesn't have one element UsernameToken. How do i remove the element from SOAP Header during response.

Below are the request and response headers.

Request SOAP Header:

```
<s:Header>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<o:UsernameToken u:Id="">
<o:Username>XXXXX</o:Username>
<o:Password>ABCC</o:Password>
</o:UsernameToken>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
```

Response SOAP Header:

```
<s:Header>
      <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="">
            <u:Created>2018-05-02T02:29:26.662Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2018-05-02T02:34:26.662Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
```

As of now the Response Header generated by service contains the UsernameToken element in addition to Timestamp element i add on successful response..

Below is the Web Method.

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("Security", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
ValidateResponse validate()
```

The Security SoapHeader is defined as:

```
 [XmlRoot("Security", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis- 
        open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class SecurityHeader : SoapHeader
    {
        private UsernameTokenHeader _header;
        private Timestamp _headerstamp;
        [XmlElement("UsernameToken")]
        public UsernameTokenHeader Header
        {
            get { return _header; }
            set { _header = value; }
        }
        [XmlElement("Timestamp", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis- 
          open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
        public Timestamp HeaderStamp
        {
            get { return _headerstamp; }
            set { _headerstamp = value; }
        }
    }
```

Now i need to delete the UsernameToken from header for response.